# Supplying parameters to ML model objects

Tags: python, machine-learning

So when we assign a variable for ML model estimator , for example:

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()

If I want to supply the parameters to the model using the variable clf, how should I do it ?

I know we can supply it in the () brackets of the classifier but how to do it with respect to clf variable.

I had parameters in a dictionary :

param = {'criterion' : 'entropy'}

then I tried clf.param or clf(param)but got error.

Instead of writing DecisionTreeClassifier(param) I want to use it in terms of clf variable.

Comment: do you know about keyword arguments? if not please learn about them, its just DecisionTreeClassifier(**param)

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, How can I use it in terms of the defined clf variable ?

Comment: What do you mean "use it in terms of clf variable"? This makes little sense to me... Do you want to instantiate a `DecisionTreeClassifier` first, and only then set its parameters? Why would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: @GregoirePelegrin. Yes , exactly what you said.  I will later use the hyperparameter tuned dictionary as a parameter for the classifier object. Can I supply the same as clf(param) ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you're after, this should do:

```py
import sklearn
from sklearn import tree
from typing import Dict
sklearn.set_config(print_changed_only=False) # Only here to force the display of default parameters in the prints


if __name__ == "__main__":
    params: Dict = {
        "criterion": "entropy",
        "splitter": "random",
        "max_depth": 65
    }
    clf: tree.DecisionTreeClassifier = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
    print(f"{clf}")
    for name, value in params.items():
        clf.__setattr__(name, value)
    print(f"{clf}")
```

This produces the following output, the first being before modification and the second after modification:

```
DecisionTreeClassifier(ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
                       max_depth=None, max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
                       min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_samples_leaf=1,
                       min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
                       random_state=None, splitter='best')
DecisionTreeClassifier(ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None, criterion='entropy',
                       max_depth=65, max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
                       min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_samples_leaf=1,
                       min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
                       random_state=None, splitter='random')
```

That said, please see the fact that we are using a private method to do this (`__setattr__`), which is usually not regarded so highly (it usually is not the proper way to do, as only the permissive structure of Python is allowing us to use these pseudo-private methods outside the scope of the class).
Also, this assumes you name the parameters correctly. While this won't throw any errors if the parameter you've entered in your dictionary doesn't exist, it will create a new attribute to this instance. In practice, this means that adding `"ducks": 5` to the `params` dictionary will create a `ducks` attribute to this particular `DecisionTreeClassifier` instance. This could potentially lead to unexpected behavior if not taken into account.

As a secondary solution, but which will be more hard coded, you can modify each parameter individually: `clf.criterion = "entropy"`. You won't be able to pass the name of the attribute as a variable, though.

Comment: I see, Thanks man! I am new to ML so I am learning alot of new things! __setattr__ is one of them.

Comment: To be more precise, `setattr` is not so much of a Machine Learning thing but a Python thing.

Comment: My brother, I meant while learning ML, I am getting to know a lot of python too. Update : I tried set_params(**param) and it worked the same as __setattr__.

Comment: This is a way better solution and I should have seen it. The `set_params` method is public, and checks for the validity of every parameter you're trying to modify before actually proceeding with the change. Additionally, while my initial method may have worked in this case, using the proper way to do things is important for you don't know what effects a change in parameter is supposed to have on other attributes/on the behavior of the object, and if not done properly, might lead to unexpected behavior.